# SPE Remoting script throws null-valued expression exception

Tags: powershell-extensions

On a fresh Windows VM I installed powershell extensions module:

```
Install-Module SPE
```

Then I am trying to invoke a remote script on my sitecore instance:

```
$url = "https://my-sitecore.azurewebsites.net"
$session = New-ScriptSession -Username admin -Password b -ConnectionUri $url
Invoke-RemoteScript -Session $session -ScriptBlock { Write-Host "Foo" }
```

But it fails with

> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At C:\Program
>   Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SPE\6.0.0\Invoke-RemoteScript.ps1:344
>   char:21
>   +                     $taskResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result
>   +                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

How can I fix it?

Comment: What version of Sitecore PowerShell Extensions do you have installed in your instance?

Comment: @MichaelWest 6.0.0, Sitecore, if that matters, is 9.2 xp0 topology

Comment: Did you enable the remoting service using a patch?

Comment: @MichaelWest no, will try to find a patch and apply it. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

This type of error appears when you have an undeclared (null) variable.
For me looks like $session is null .

Can you update your script in this way:

```
$session = New-ScriptSession -Username "admin" -Password "b" -ConnectionUri $url
```

Comment: Thank you! Tried it, but still the same error. And if I try to just `$session` I can see the object with all the correct properties (and values). Only empty value on $session is `Credential`. But `Password` and `Username` are there

Comment: Tried the example with an extra line of `$credential = Get-Credential` and passing it to `-Credential $credential`. Same result...

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the error was because of different versions of SPE installed locally and on the sitecore instance.

I used a sitecore vanila package with pre-installed SPE and a couple of extra packages and the SPE version was 5.0

Locally I used the latest - 6.0 and they are not backward compatible!
But from the good news - SPE 5.0 works with sitecore 9.2

To solve the issue I had to downgrade installed SPE:

```
Remove-Package SPE
Uninstall-Package SPE
Install-Package -Name SPE -RequiredVersion 5.0
```